# Shrinkage methods - are they any good for statistical inference or should they be used for prediction goals only?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, model-selection, aic, regularization

I am working on my master thesis with a goal to find regressors which influence companies' decisions on how to pay for a target in acquisitions (cash, stock or a mix of both).

I have 13 regressors to start with, I am using a multinomial logit to fit my data and as of now I am trying to find the best possible model by a feature (variable) selection techniques. I have started off with basic methods like stepwise/backwards/forwards followed by all possible regression approach. Gradually, I am trying to use better and more sophisticated methods (my supervisor recommended me to use a BMA approach too, I want to keep this one for the very end of my work though).

Right now, I have come across the shrinkage methods (lasso, ridge, elasticity net). The thing is, I am not sure whether these should not be used for predictive goals rather than for statistical inference (see [Shmueli, 2010](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/157/Papers/shmueli.pdf)).

I would like to hear your valuable opinions on this topic (references for academic/non-academic papers welcomed) as well as recommendations as to which further suitable methods for model selection to use.

Second thing - the aforementioned paper deals with a suitable criterion for model selection as well. The paper claims that AIC should be used for prediction goals, on the other hand BIC suits better statistical inference goals. I have been using AIC so far through my entire analysis as I have not encountered any paper/post which would advise otherwise.

Comment: I think Hastie and Tibshirani have a book about sparse methods.  They may talk about inference using penalized regression in that book.  I suggest looking there.

Comment: A big problem with inference for regularized models is the difficulty of calculating confidence intervals for the coefficients.

Comment: For inference maybe pass to bayesian versions of regularization?

Comment: @DemetriPananos and efron and hastie have a book too :) https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf Computer age statistical inference